# How to create a list with "grouped" in Scala through Gatling?

Tags: arrays, scala, arraylist, gatling

I am trying to make a list which groups elements in chunks of 3.
I am not trying anything elaborate, just initialising a list with values and then telling it to group the elements. When I run this it claims:
***'hook-64' crashed with 'j.u.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named 'listToGroup' is defined', forwarding to the next one*** so I understand it is not recognising the declaration.

Here is the code:

```
 val SessionVal = scenario("aaa").exec{
    session =>
      val listToGroup = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
      listToGroup.grouped(3).toList

      session
  }
  val printSessionVal = scenario("print me").exec{
    session =>
      println(session("listToGroup").as[String])
      session
  }
```

The call:

```
 def teacherResourcesPageFlow: ChainBuilder = exitBlockOnFail(
    group("Resources Calls") {
      exec(getProductCategoryIds)
         ...
         ...
        .exec(SessionVal)
        .exec(printSessionVal)
         ...
    })
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include the line **session.set("listToGroup", listToGroup)**:

```
  val SessionVal = scenario("listArry").exec{
    session =>
      val listToGroup = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
      listToGroup.grouped(4).toList
      session.set("listToGroup", listToGroup)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this through a [feeder](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/feeder/).

In your case it will look like this:

```
val listArry = Iterator.continually(Map("listArry" ->  List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).grouped(4)))

scenario("listArry")
  .feed(listArry)
```